# I need to prove that $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{R}^+\cong U$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I need to prove that $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{R}^+\cong U$ by the theorem:
$G/\ker(\varphi)\cong Im(\varphi)$.

$U$ - Is the circle unit.
$\mathbb{R}^+=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}\Big|x>0\right\}$ (So the action of the group is multiply ,and $e=1$).
$\mathbb{C}^*= \left( \left\{c\in \mathbb{C}\big|c\ne0\right\},\cdot\right), therefor\; e=1$.  (Same as $\mathbb{R}^+$).

I trying to find $\varphi:\mathbb{C}^*\to U$, $\ker\varphi=\mathbb{R}^+$ and $Im\varphi=U$

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The polar representation of complex numbers gives you $\mathbb{C}^* \cong \mathbb{R}^+ \times U$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\phi: z \mapsto \frac{z}{|z|}$

Comment: And why $\ker(\varphi)=\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: In $U$, the identity element is $1$, so you have to resolve $\phi(z) = 1$...

Comment: Yes, but why $-5$ for example bring me to other value then $1$??

Comment: What is $\frac{5}{|5|}$ ?

Comment: 1, but I need that only positive numbers will bring me to 1....

Comment: Oh, I see: $-5\mapsto -1$... (I hope I'm right).

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: And if it was $\mathbb{R}^*$ insted, what was the function?

Comment: Look at the function $\psi(z) = \frac{z^2}{|z^2|}$

Comment: But $\ker(psi)\ne\mathbb{R}^*$. Because there is a complex numbers like $3+3i$ or $3-3i$ that brings you back to 1, no?

Comment: You should answer yourself.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I write $U=S^1=\{e^{i\theta}|\theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Note that if $z \in \mathbb{C}^*$, then $z =|z|e^{i \theta}$. Define a map $f:\mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ by $f(z)=f(|z|e^{i\theta})=e^{i \theta}$. Check its image and the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

$\varphi: r(\cos\alpha+ i\sin\alpha)\to (\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi(z)= arg(z)$ this sets $ker(\psi) = \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: What is $arg(\cdots)$? thank you!

Comment: $arg(re^{i\theta}) = \theta$  we restrict $\theta \in [0, \pi)$